# Sublime Text 3 - PHP - object operator and double arrow operator

Tags: php, netbeans, sublimetext3

Recently I've begin moving to sublime text 3 from Netbeans.

I've discovered almost all needed features but still can't find one.

There is a cool feature in Netbeans:
[image]

It does the following. If I have such code:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->someMethod();
```

I don't need actually to type   - and then shift + > to get -> . It's enough just to presss  - sign and  Netbeans figures out on his own that it should be  -> .
The same is applied to array.

I understand that Sublime doesn't do as deep code analysis as Netbeans does.

Of course it would perfect solution if it could figure out like Netbeans does.

But I would happy to replace - sign on numpad keyboard to  -> always.

I've tried snippets. It looks like this:
[image]

It works ok. But only if it goes as the first symbol in the word. 
But then I need to reference an object referencing never goes first.

I can't believe that all people type manually every time - and shift+> to get referencing the object.  There must be better way.

Any ideas? How did you tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no silver bullet which would kill any beast.

Though ST is a cool editor it's just editor, it's good for js, scss,css, python where Netbeans sucks but too bad for php.

Probably I would be happy with ST for PHP  if I didn't know that you can get more boosting using full-blown IDE.

So frontend development will be carried on ST and backend on Netbeans.

**Edit**

Of course I tried the whole bunch of available plugins. This is the list of tried:
[image]

Comment: Did you try using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) ? Sublime Text can have multiple powerful add ons.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the <kbd>-</kbd> key with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> in all situations in Sublime Text (meaning if you want to write, for example `1 - 2`, you would have to type <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>, you can do the following:

- From the `Preferences` menu in Sublime Text
- Click `Keybindings - User`
- Write `[{ "keys": ["-"], "command": "insert", "args": { "characters": "->" } }]` (note that this assumes that you don't already have anything in the user keybinding file. If you do, before the `]` at the end of the file, type `,` and the above without the enclosing `[` and `]` characters. The file needs to be a valid JSON array of keybindings.)
- Save it
- Try typing `-` and see the magic

You may be able to do some magic with [contexts](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html#contexts) to get this keybinding only for PHP syntax files, or you could just write a simple Python plugin that your keybinding would execute, which would enter `-` in the document if it is not a PHP file and `->` if it is.